# html input element name missing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically creating a table with checkboxes and in order to implement Select All functionality I'm assigning them all the same name. For some reason the name attribute is missing.
https://jsfiddle.net/slzfn/76q6y8ow/19/

Code snippet:

```
 t.append(
  `<tr>
    <td>`+ d.AName +`</td>
    <td>` + d.TName + `</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tick_track" checked='` + d.tick  + `'></td>
  </tr>`);
```

Comment: I don't see any dinamically created table there, just static `HTML`. There is your problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/76q6y8ow/20/ If you wrap it in body the javascript actually runs when DOM is ready and you will see the names.

Comment: @user5480949 I think the characters ` and ´ are invalid at this postion.